# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on new website

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns

I have created a website, configured the domain and so on. Everything seems to work great in my laptop, my phone... but not my Desktop PC

When I go to [www.mynewwebsite.com](http://www.mynewwebsite.com), I am greeted by an error "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

[image]

This happens in Chrome AND Firefox, which makes me think that this is a system-wide problem. I have seen some solutions online, for instance to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and change it from this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search fritz.box
```

to this:

```
#nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.4
options edns0 trust-ad
search fritz.box
```

and then run `sudo service network-manager restart`. But this changes nothing, and besides, the file gets reverted to its original configuration.

I am using 20.04. What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a DNS issue, check what IP address is being returned by `ping yourwebsite.com` or `nslookup yourwebsite.com`

Try flushing your DNS cache by running `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches` and/or `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`

How long ago was the website registered etc? If it's only very recently then the address/IP may not be propagated across all internet nameservers, it may take 24-48 hours.

If you want to set custom DNS nameservers (e.g. the Google ones in your example) rather than whatever your ISP/router is giving you then add them into the Ubuntu Network Settings GUI.

Comment: It didnt help, maybe I do have to simply wait, I registered the web not 1 hour ago